# I keep getting this error in my node code. DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a small server in node.js. Unfortunately it keeps giving me this error.

```
(node:8412) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
    fs.js:113
          throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
```

Basically, i am just importing all the required modules. Then i go ahead and 
 parse a request to check if the filename in the request is a file or directory or something that is unavailable on the server.Below is my code:

```
//include the module http,url,path,fs
const http=require('http');
const url=require('url');
const path=require('path');
const fs=require('fs');

//define the mime types that we would be using  
const mimeTypes={
    "html":"text/html",
    "jpeg":"image/jpeg",
    "jpg":"image/jpg",
    "png":"image/png",
    "js":"text/javascript",
    "css":"text/css"
};

//define the host name to local machine IP 
const hostname='127.0.0.1';

//define the port on which over server would be runnning 
const port = 3000;

//lets create the server  
const server= http.createServer(function(req,resp){
    //get the path name 
    var uri=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    // get eh file name 
    var filename =path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(uri));
    console.log('loading'+ uri);
    var stats;
    // cehck to see if the file name is actually a file directory or non existant  stuff 
    try{
        stats=fs.lstat(filename);
        if(stats.isFile()){
            var mimeType=mimeType[path.extname(filename).split(".").reverse()[0]];
            resp.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':mimeType});
            var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
            fileStream.pipe(resp);
            resp.end(); 
        } else if(stats.isDirectory()){
            resp.writeHead(302,{
                'Location':'index.html'
            });
            resp.end();    
        }
        else{
            resp.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
            resp.write('500 Internal server error \n');
            resp.end();
        }


    }catch(e)
    {
        resp.writeHead(404,{'Content-type':'text/plain'});
        resp.write('404 Not Found \n');
        resp.end();
        return;
    }


}).listen(3000);

//lets create a listner to make sure that the port is running  when the code is called 
server.listen(port,hostname,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're calling an asynchronous method without a callback.

Comment: I am fairly new to this. Sorry for bothering the pros.

Answer (score 2):

fs.lstat is an asynchronous call you can either add a call back or use the synchronous version of the call; fs.lstatSync

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstat_path_options_callback